# Why is there no current in a magnet even though magnetic field is present?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Why is there no current in a magnet even though magnetic field is present?

We know current is produced due to magnetic field and vice versa. But there is no current produced in a magnet, why?

Comment: A _changing_ magnetic field generates a current (in conductors). A static magnetic field does not generate a current.

Comment: This might help - [MAGNETS: How Do They Work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFAOXdXZ5TM)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Static magnetism is caused by atomic magnetic moments. Certain atoms, such as iron, have unpaired electron spins$^*$ that persist in materials and can then align to give [ferromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferromagnetism). There exists no understanding of electron spin in terms of a model exhibiting rotating charge or energy. A static magnet is a material with [magnetization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetization#Magnetization_current) ($\vec M$)$^{**}$ and the divergency of this is the *bound current* ${\vec j}_b = {\vec \nabla} \times {\vec M}$. For a homogeneously magnetized cylinder a $j_b$ occurs at the cylindrical surface. In this sense also permanent magnetism originates from a current.

$^*$ Orbital contributions may be mixed in by spin-orbit coupling.

$^{**}$ Like the magnetic field, $\vec M$ is an [axial vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector).

Comment: You wrote "There exists no understanding of electron spin in terms of a model exhibiting rotating charge or energy." This is not quite right, see, for example Ohanian: "What is spin?" Am. J. Phys. 54 (6), June 1986, (and also his EM book). Quote form the abstract: "According to the prevailing belief, the spin of the electron or of some other particle is a mysterious internal angular momentum for which no concrete physical picture is available, and for which there is no classical analog. However, on the basis of an old calculation by Belinfante [ Physica 6, 887 ( 1939) ] ,...

Comment: ....it can be shown that the spin may be regarded as an angular momentum generated by a circulating flow of energy in the wave field of the electron. Likewise, the magnetic moment may be regarded as generated by a circulating flow of charge in the wave field. This provides an intuitively appealing picture and establishes that neither the spin nor the magnetic moment are "internal"-they are not associated with the internal structure of the electron, but rather with the structure of its wave field....

Comment: ... Furthermore, a comparison between calculations of· angular momentum in the Dirac and electromagnetic fields shows that the spin of the electron is entirely analogous to the angular momentum carried by a classical circularly polarized wave."

Comment: @hyportnex While I completely agree with these statements, do they actually constitute a model?

Comment: yes, it is *a* model, read it, Ohanian is a very good writer, you can read it here by clicking on the academia.edu link https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C22&q=Ohanian%3A+%22What+is+spin%3F%22+&btnG=

Comment: @hyportnex The expressions Ohanian obtains by partial integration are closely related to the Noether orbital and spin angular momentum distributions obtained from the Fermi lagrangian, with the difference that these are _separately_ conserved. See my paper https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0106078.

Comment: @hyportnex I am familiar with Belinfante's work and Ohanian makes many valid points. I don't agree with Ohanian that Belinfante's result contributes to a better understanding of spin. Here is my reasoning. If, as I conjecture, spin results from rotation of a small structure then the kinetic effects of this are absent from the momentum and stress distribution outside this structure. Note: the same holds for a spinning cue ball. Spin related motion is contained in the wave function at the scale of the electron radius, which is as yet indistinguishable from zero.

Answer (score 6):

The magnet is composed of tiny magnetic moments that are essentially current loops. At atomic level, these come from both orbital angular momentum and spin angular momentum. This is the orbital motion of the electrons around the nuclei and the intrinsic spin/magnetic moment of the electron.